# Where are the "Publishing options" for a node stored in the database?

Tags: database, users

I need to order a column in a custom module by whether the node is published or not. Can't figure out where this is being stored in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the status field in the node table (in Drupal 7).

Comment: Thank you... same in D6 apparently (that's what I'm using).